# Migrating source code from PVCS to Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, pvcs

I am trying to migrate the project source code with revision history from PVCS to Bitbucket.

I have searched a lot & cannot find the proper resolution for this. Is there any tools available for this?

Comment: You've tagged this for both Bitbucket Server and Bitbucket Cloud. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: It's about Bitbucket Server..